# Faster way to loop over and assign to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops

I have written a piece of code to loop over my entire dataframe and if the condition `== '[Blank]'` is met then it replaces that with an empty string `''`. However, the method I am using is very slow and I know there must be a faster way of doing this but I am not sure. I need to be able to iterate over the dataframe and assign to it based on a condition. I included my code below:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in df.columns:
        if df.loc[i, j] == '[Blank]':
            df.loc[i, j] = ''
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of your dataframe?

Comment: But could you not just use `df.replace`? So it would be `df.replace('[Blank]','')`

Comment: @FiachraBarry Then, if you wish, you can accept the answer below by @SifatAmin, because that is referring to `df.replace`.

Comment: @FiachraBarry I added my answer too, except either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace BLANK column by column or from the whole data frame.

```
df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].replace('[BLANK]', '') 
# BY column

for col in df.columns:
 df[col] = df[col].replace('[BLANK]', '')

or
df.replace('[BLANK]', '') # from whole dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `df.replace` to replace all values in the dataframe:

```
df.replace('[Blank]','')
```